# Noun case and plurality

Tags: грамматика, падежи

Take a sentence such as *Я имею **основания** ей не верить*.

If основания is **accusative**, then it must be **plural**. And thus the translation will be: I have **reasons** not to trust her.

But if основания is **genitive**, then it must be **singular**. And thus the translation will be: I have a **reason** not to trust her.

I'm sure native Russian speakers can identify the correct form instantly from years of input, but what is going on behind the scenes here?

Maybe I must simply know that there are no rules that make **основания** genitive here, and therefore it must be accusative, and mean reason**s**, not reason?

Comment: The first one is correct, I cannot imagine Genitive here. Genetive is translated into English with "of", so if it were Genitive, the translation would be "I have of the reason not to trust her", total nonsence.

Comment: Get used to saying "есть/нет" instead of "иметь/не иметь". "Иметь" is said by all those officials, politicians and other dull guys in the TV. Normal people almost never say like this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, a side note: unlike most other languages, you don't use *имею* in Russian unless there's a reason to. See this question:

- [Иметь vs у меня for physical things](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C-vs-%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F-for-physical-things/)

In your case, you say

> У меня есть основания ей не верить

Now, *имею* (or *быть* in proximal possessive sense) does not govern genitive when positive, but does when negative. That's how the language works. It is:

> *У меня есть + nom.* (or *я имею + acc.*)

but

> *У меня нет* (or *я не имею*) *+ gen.*

Hence, you can say

> У меня нет основания

which is negative, hence the object is in genitive, hence it is singular, and the whole sentence means "I don't have a reason"; or you can say

> У меня есть основания

which is positive, hence the object is in nominative, hence it is plural. This means "I have (my) reasons".

Comment: `У меня нет основания` - this one would also sound naturally in plural like `У меня нет оснований`

Comment: @UVV: of course it would. The question was how to tell *основания* (sg. gen.) from *основания* (pl. nom.)

Answer (score 3):

You're correct - there are rules that make it clear. The Russian speaker instictively knows that the verb **иметь** takes the accusative and not the genitive case. However in a negative context, it sometimes does take the genitive:

Это не имеет **смысла**. [< **смысл** m. *sense, meaning*]

*This doesn't make* [lit: *have*] *sense*.

So to answer your question, what's going on behind the scenes here is a simple matter of **case government**, which can vary from verb to verb. For instance, the verb *help* takes a direct object in English, yet an indirect [dative] object in Russian. With this knowledge, the Russian sees **Президент помогает бедным** *The president helps the poor* and instantly knows that here *бедным* is the dative plural and not the instrumental singular, for example, which have identical endings in adjectives.